# connecting mysql to python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

i get an error when i try to run a stored procedure 
import MySQLdb

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="root", # your password
                      db="P_CAT_teetws") # name of the data base

# you must create a Cursor object. It will let
#  you execute all the queries you need
cur = db.cursor() 
name="shakiiraa"
cur.execute("CALL sp_ORDER_BY_name %s",name)

# print all the first cell of all the rows
for row in cur.fetchall() :
    print row[0]
```

_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''shakiiraa'' at line 1")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cur.execute("CALL sp_ORDER_BY_name(%s)",name)
```